# How the .htaccess file is rewrite/overwrite?

Tags: web-services, .htaccess, joomla

How the `.htaccess` file  rewrites? my website was working fine yesterday but it's not working today. I didn;t change anything. There are some  deny access codes is  in the .htaccess. My site is hacked?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the .htaccess file can be the target for an attack. To find if your .htaccess file has been changed, compare it with an original htaccess.txt from the Joomla installation package. If it is, you may simply restore the original one in place of the hacked one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The content of the file has been changed by the  server administrator, because of spam post in forum.